# Ruby/Mongo: Why am I receiving uninitialized constant MongoClient error?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am following [this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Tutorial) tutorial but I've hit a problem. I keep getting the error:

```
server.rb:10:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Mongo::MongoClient (NameError)
```

I am using the following gems:

```
Using bson 4.1.1
Using bson_ext 1.5.1
Using daemons 1.2.3
Using eventmachine 1.2.0.1
Using rack 1.6.4
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using bundler 1.12.5
Using mongo 2.2.5
Using rack-protection 1.5.3
Using thin 1.7.0
Using sinatra 1.4.7
```

My code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

require 'mongo'
include Mongo

mongo_client = MongoClient.new("localhost", 27017)
```

I've required the mongo gem and included the Mongo class. Why isn't `MongoClient` being recognised? Why am I receiving the error?

Answer (score 0):

Because `MongoClient` doesn't exist in that version of the mongo driver. As of the 2.0 version of the driver, the client class is `Mongo::Client`.

The 2.0 version introduced a number of big changes to the api, so I wouldn't recommend following a tutorial written for earlier versions - it looks like that page was last updated in Feb 2014. The mongodb docs have an up to date [tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-driver-tutorial/) but for some reason the old tutorial is top of the google results.